# Creating a tag cloud from a list in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am getting a list from an API call. I would like to be able to display a tagcloud based on the words in the list.

I have seen some other possible solutions that generate the HTML in the view function but if I am using templates, how can I bypass this step? Also, solutions like using the [django plugin](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) the seem to require the use of models which I feel is not necessary in my case.

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this.  Personally I would manipulate the list of tags into this format in you view:

```
tags = [
    { 'tag': 'django', 'size': 10 },
    { 'tag': 'python', 'size': 8 },
    { 'tag': 'Australia', 'size': 1 },
    { 'tag': 'coffee', 'size': 6 },
    { 'tag': 'pycon', 'size': 3 },
    { 'tag': 'html', 'size': 9 },
]
```

In your template:

```
<div class="tag-cloud">
    {% for t in tags %}
        <a href="/blog/tag/{{ t.tag }}/" class="size-{{ t.size }}">{{ t.tag }}</a> 
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

In your CSS:

```
.tag-cloud a.size-1 { font-size: 1.1em }
.tag-cloud a.size-2 { font-size: 1.2em }
.tag-cloud a.size-3 { font-size: 1.3em }
.tag-cloud a.size-4 { font-size: 1.4em }
.tag-cloud a.size-5 { font-size: 1.5em }
.tag-cloud a.size-6 { font-size: 1.6em }
.tag-cloud a.size-7 { font-size: 1.7em }
.tag-cloud a.size-8 { font-size: 1.8em }
.tag-cloud a.size-9 { font-size: 1.9em }
.tag-cloud a.size-10 { font-size: 2em }
```

Comment: I just created a small template tag that allows exactly this without the need of adding code to the view. It operates by creating a new attribute (such as size) on the fly from another method/attribute of a Hash or a QuerySet: https://github.com/niconoe/django-nuages-tag

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the tag list in the template and use the "random" filter over an integer list for the inline font-size style.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#random

**views.py**

```
...
sizes = [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
tags = ["one", "two", "three"]
...
```

**index.html**

```
...
{% for tag in tags %}
    <a href="/some/url/with/{{ tag }}/" style="font-size: {{ sizes|random }}px">{{ tag }}</a>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install worldcloud

pip install matplotlib
```

In `views.py`:

```
def cloud(request):   
    object1   =   obj.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)
    words =   list(object1)

    # image configurations
    background_color = "#fff"
    height = 720
    width = 1080

   data = dict()
   for word in words:
      word = word.lower()
      data[word] = data.get(word, 0) + 1

    word_cloud = WordCloud(
    background_color=background_color,
    width=width,
    height=height
    )

word_cloud.generate_from_frequencies(data)
word_cloud.to_file('../cdn/cdn_medias/clouds/image.png')

context = {}
return  render(request,'object/cloud.html',context)
```

In your template:

```
<img src="/media/clouds/image.png" class="img-fluid w-50">
```